# SOAP service and REST Client in one app

Tags: java, apache, rest, soap, client

I am working on a webservice app that takes SOAP requests on one end with a id, I wrote java beans and generated wsdl. It is working fine independently. Then I made a REST Client using apache HttpClient using the interface CloseableHttpClient. This part works independently as well when I make a rest request with a static ID.

Now when I merged the REST client code with the soap service and try to test it using SoapUI, I get :
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

The webservice is working fine but when I call the REST client the thread hangs up at when trying to execute.
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

Im thinking there's some design issues with how I'm merging this. Right now, I'm calling im Instantiating the object that makes the rest call within the Soap Request class and calling the method from within the soap request class
Can anyone please help me point to the right direction about how I should design it. I was not able to find any examples on this either online
Thanks

Comment: some code would help probably :).

Comment: Add the exception stack trace, it will help a lot. My first guess is there is some kind of library that comes in two versions. One (newer) is being used in your IDE and the other (older) is embedded in your run-time environment (for example in the server) and takes precedence over the first one. OR maybe SOAP and REST parts of your application are using the same class but with a little bit different API expected. The exception suggests the reflection was used to invoke something, it makes an error showing up only at runtime. Without the details of the exception it's hard to tell anything more.